# PHP 7 / Symfony 3.4 Generate video from multiple images using ffmpeg tool

Tags: php, symfony, ffmpeg

I recently started development on Symfony 3.4. I would like to generate video from a set of images using ffmpeg tool. And in this video I would like to display a text on start of the video and some text at the end of the video.

Is there any already existing Symfony/PHP package which I can use and generate the video out of images?

So far on searching, I came across following two packages, but when on trial I could not generate the video out of multiple images.

1. [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)
   Tried with this package but did not get any success and came across this existing [issue](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/410) which says that its not possible using this package.
2. [ffmpeg-php-class](https://github.com/olaferlandsen/ffmpeg-php-class)
   Also tried with this package, with reference to [Example # 20](https://github.com/olaferlandsen/ffmpeg-php-class#example-20-image-to-video) , but it only generates video for the single image only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save all your images in single folder and name it in format `img###.png` where `#` is sequence number. Then use [slideshow FFMPEG command](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Sequential) to generate video:

```
shel_exec("{$ffmpegPath} -framerate 24 -i img%03d.png output.mp4");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I was wondering if I can use any existing php package/symfony bundle which is already there and acts as a wrapper package to the above command. Any suggestions for the same?

Comment: @KD-Freelancer Actually we only use FFMPEG executable.

Comment: Ohh okay. I tried your command, it works fine for ffmpeg version 2.8.11, Ubuntu 16.04.1 but it does not work for ffmpeg version 3.4, Ubuntu 16.04.1 and ffmpeg version 3.3.3, Ubuntu 14.04.4.

Comment: I believe it was the issue of particular player. So the command works but like I also mentioned, I want to show some text on start and end of the video which is being generated from images. So do you have any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: @KD-Freelancer Generate images with that text already applied.

Comment: Yes I was aware of that option, but in my case the text will be decided runtime, i.e it will not be fixed. So one possible option can be to runtime generate the image with that text, but is there any other possible option?

Comment: Can I add an image at the end of a video named video.mp4? Can you please help me how can I achieve that?